# Создание .bat файла с для запуска бота телеграм

Tags: python, telegram-bot, cmd, bat

[image: Скриншот требуемых действий]

Требуется создать батник, который сначала перейдет в нужную папку, потом запустит файл телеграм бота. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Просто взять и написать эти самые две команды как есть в bat-файл

Comment: Я пробовал. Не работает. Консоль сразу закрывается

Comment: Почему не работает? Какие ошибки пишет?

Comment: Никаких. Просто консолька открывается на миллисекунду и сразу закрывается

Comment: Значит сперва откройте консольку, потом в этой открытой консольке запустите bat-файл и прочитайте текст ошибки

Comment: Ну или добавьте команду pause в bat-файл, чтобы консолька не закрывалась

Comment: D:\Рабочий стол>cd C://Bott
D:\Рабочий стол>python bot.py
python: can't open file 'D:\\Рабочий стол\\bot.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
D:\Рабочий стол>pause

Comment: Не переходит в папку

Comment: Для перехода в папку другого диска нужно сперва сменить диск с помощью команды `c:`

Comment: Или к команде cd добавить опцию /D

Comment: Все заработало. Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Решение:

```
c:
cd C://Bott 
python bot.py
pause
```

Нужно было выполнить переход с диска D на С и поставить паузу для поиска ошибок